# Windsor Castle and WCF REST Service Template

Tags: wcf, rest, castle-windsor

I'm pretty new at creating REST services, but I've been looking to the new 'WCF REST Service Template 40(CS)'....

However I'd like to be able to use Windsor Castle and Inceptors, but haven't really been able to figure out how to do this.....

The new 'WCF REST Service Template' doesn't seem to implement an interface, so how do I configure Castle to do it's dynamic stuff?

TIA

Søren

Answer (score 0):

It's not something simple to do. You need to deal with some WCF extensibility mechanisms and implement a custom IInstanceProvider behavior for hooking up Windsor as IoC in WCF. I wrote a post a long time ago about how to do this with the Microsoft Object Builder, but you can reuse most of it with Windsor,

http://weblogs.asp.net/cibrax/archive/2007/12/13/wcf-dependency-injection-behavior.aspx

Thanks
Pablo.

Comment: Hi Pablo
Thanks for your reply...
What I was looking for was a way to do it with the new WCF REST templates introduced in VS2010..... they don't seem to be working with Interfaces....
Doing it the normal way, is explained here:
http://www.mckelt.com/post/2009/02/03/WCF-Windsor-Interceptor2c-AOP-with-Logging-and-Exception-Handler-Interceptor.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Found a pretty good example here:

http://codebetter.com/howarddierking/2010/01/19/vanilla-yet-composable-http-services-with-wcf-4-and-windsor/